# tikzpicture differences plot

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm doing an analysis where I look for different effects of a reform between states. I would like to post my estimates using tixzpicture, to show the effects of each state in reference to a normalised state (set to zero). I'm having a hard time doing this in latex, and could use some tips.

These two pictures show an example of what I want. In the second picture I would like state names where the years are written, and each states estimate with confidence intervalls (I do not want the line between the dots, or the red line). Zero would be my reference. The first picture shows something close to it as well.

Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error bars facility of pgfplots might be a good starting point. See page 316 of the v1.17 manual -  http://mirror.physik-pool.tu-berlin.de/pub/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf

Comment: HI Lars, welcome to TexExchange Could you also be more specific about your issue? Is it about drawing a plot or the confidence intervals, or?

Comment: @user1729210. My issue is both, I would say. I'm a beginner to using graphs/plots in latex. I've been able to make som basic plots so far, but I'm not sure where to begin with this one. Thanks for the tip with the manual, it helps a lot for the confidence intervals!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! This is a *start*. user1729210 already told you to look at error bars, this fleshes this suggestion out to some extent. These are just examples, and if you have the data in form of tables you can use a modified version of this code. There are many variants that produce similar results.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily] 
\matrix{
\begin{axis}[ytick={0,1,2,3},
    yticklabels={Turn circle,Length,Trunk space,Mileage},
    minor ytick={0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5},yminorgrids]
  \addplot+[only marks, color=blue,yshift=4pt,error bars/.cd,
  x dir=both,x explicit,error mark options={scale=0}
      ] coordinates {
   (-10,0) +=(200,0) -=(250,0) 
   (20,1) +=(30,0) -=(40,0) 
   (100,2) +=(110,0) -=(110,0) 
   (-100,3) +=(110,0) -=(110,0) 
      };
  \addplot+[only marks, color=red,mark=*,yshift=-4pt,error bars/.cd,
  x dir=both,x explicit,error mark options={scale=0}
      ] coordinates {
   (-30,0) +=(600,0) -=(700,0) 
   (100,1) +=(40,0) -=(40,0) 
   (100,2) +=(110,0) -=(110,0) 
   (-10,3) +=(40,0) -=(50,0) 
      };
   \draw[red] (0,0) coordinate (O) (O|-current axis.south)
    -- (O|-current axis.north);
\end{axis}\\

\begin{axis}[ymin=-1.2,ymax=2.2]
  \addplot[
  error bars/.cd,
  y dir=both,y explicit,
      ] coordinates {
   (1910,-0.1) +=(0,0.5) -=(0,0.5) 
   (1920,-0.15) +=(0,0.35) -=(0,0.4) 
   (1930,0.1) +=(0,0.3) -=(0,0.25) 
      };
\end{axis}\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, @Schrödinger's cat. I've been playing around with the set-up you made, and it is starting to look good. I'm having trouble with another issue: When I add many states (i.e. the list "Milage, Trunk Space, ..., + 15"), the text on the y-axis gets crowded. I can resize it to make it bigger, but it seems to stay square. Is there a way to make it a long rectangle form?

Comment: @Lars I am sorry, from the description I cannot really understand what you are doing. Would you mind asking a separate question in which you post the code such that others see what the problem is? Asking questions is free and that way you avoid misinterpretations.

Comment: I found the solution! Simply changing width and height in the \pgfplotsset{width=10cm,height=15cm,compat=1.16} made it look good. Thanks again!